# How to change screen by using cross button?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to close the fingerprint screen as if the user doesn't have a fingerprint in mobile so they can move to login with username and password screen. you can check in the attached image I have used an ImageView of cross icon by clicking on it user should be redirected using the following code:

```
    imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.close_fingerprint);

    imageView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (FingerprintActivity.this, Login_Fragment.class);
            startActivity (intent);
            finish ();
        }
    });
```

But when I click on the close icon the whole application is closed.

[Landing Screen of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgLax.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack
> and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away
> from it and it's no longer visible on screen

Just add in the activity on manifest

```
android:noHistory="true"
```